# jQuery - Export HTML table with Tree Structure to PDF/Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

**HTML Table Structure**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" name="tableID" id="activity" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="height:24px !important" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Name</th>
        <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Category</th>
        <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Created</th>
        <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Status</th>
        <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Hours</th>
        <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:20px;color:#ff7a85">Development</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">0</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=130">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(130,0,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:40px;color:#0074a2">Bug fixing</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">120</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=131">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(131,130,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:60px;color:#33B940">dev2</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">100</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=9309">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(9309,131,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:80px;color:#ffa62f">dev3</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Inactive</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">100</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=9310">Edit</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:60px;color:#33B940">task2</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">100</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=9311">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(9311,131,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:40px;color:#0074a2">Development</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">60</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=133">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(133,130,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:60px;color:#33B940">testing1</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">100</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=9312">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(9312,133,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr><tr style="border:1px solid #ccc"><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;padding-left:40px;color:#0074a2">dev1</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Development</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">John Doe</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">Active</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc">100</td><td style="border:1px solid #ccc"><a href="http://10.103.3.96/timesheet_bijal/manage/edittask/index?project_id=478&amp;id=9308">Edit</a> / <a onclick="delete_task(9308,130,478)" style="cursor:pointer">Deactivate</a> </td></tr></tbody></table>

<table>
    <tr id="footerExport">
        <td id="exportpdf"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pdf.png" title="Export to PDF" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Included jquery scripts for HTML Table Export**

```
http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php
```

Here Project Tasks are listed down in parent-child relation and shown in a tree structure as below

[image]

The following fiddle exports the data in PDF format, but somehow the tree view is not maintained.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jWAJ7/1139/)

1) How can I show the data in PDF format as its shown in the attached image maintaining tree view and task order ?

2) Clicking on PDF icon in fiddle displays the output in Firefox and not in Chrome.

3) If not using any plugin, how could I export the shown HTML structure, in PDF/Excel format maintaining tree view ?

Comment: first look in browser url that is in 
data:application/pdf;base64,
format and you can use also Nreco pdf generator

Comment: @AmitSengar, I am already using a plugin as mentioned in the link. Also if you could post some snippet explaining your concern, would be great

Comment: you have to open new windows in your case and you don't want use this plugin then you can use Nreco pdf generator to make pdf(may be it's an option for you).
chk this "http://fiddle.jshell.net/jWAJ7/1139/show/"

Comment: a quick look at `tableExport.js` shows that this plugin does not maintain CSS ... so it is translation of HTML, but not the styling

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, but it is a bit messy.
I tried some special ACSII code to prepend spaces or tabs but they didn't work. So i did this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#exportpdf').bind('click', function (e) {
        $(".lvl1").prepend("|");
        $(".lvl2").prepend("|  ");
        $(".lvl3").prepend("|    ");
        $(".lvl4").prepend("|       ");
        $('#activity').tableExport({ type: 'pdf', escape: 'false', htmlContent:'false' });
        $(".lvl1").text().substr(1);
        $(".lvl2").text().substr(3);
        $(".lvl3").text().substr(5);
        $(".lvl4").text().substr(8);
    });
});
```

This prepends the text just before the pdf generation with a | (can be any char from your keyboard) and some trailing spaces. This way your parent child relation is visible in the pdf file, but has a | on each table row.

Also you have to add the 'level' class to each row. With lvl1 to be the upper parent and lvl 4 to be the lowest child.

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;..." class="lvl1">Development</span>
```

And to remove the spaces when the pdf is generated you have to use substr. The number is the character to start from (zero based, so 1 is the second char of a string). Hope this solves your solution.